# 360° Rotating Product Video but as a 2D Video

Tags: adobe, after-effects, adobe-premiere

I have a product video, of a product rotating on a (a: white b:green background – green is kind of bad, since my product is white and I get a lot of color spillovers)
I would to make a video clean background and clean rotation, so I could do something like tte Amazon 360° 
BUT as a 2D Video.

Is Premiere Pro with After Effects a right place to start?
Maybe someone knows a better solution for this?

I have found poly cam. I could use this, make 1000 images, and then clean it up in blender, then make the scene. But the product is quite complex.